# Listening events from CUPS by dbus?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, raspbian, dbus, cups

During to CUPS I should be able to listen events from printers by dbus. I have printer installed, cups service is working.

I tried to use D-Feet, dbus-monitor but there is no interface/object called ***/org/cups/cupsd/Notifier*** which is implemented as notifier (http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/printing/cups.git/tree/notifier/dbus.c?h=debian/jessie)

How to start this notifier to be able to listen to events from printers?